# Google Sheets Formula: Sum if Substring in range of cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two columns:

```
Col A                    Col B
01.02.2020               17
03.11.2020               24
03.11.2020               12
```

I tried to sum Col B, based on the substring of Col A like so:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,MID(A:A,4,2)="02",B:B)
=SUMIF(A:A,MID(A:A,4,2)="11",B:B)
```

Which means: If it's the second (XX.02.XXXX) month, it should sum the values from Col B based on that. If it's the 11th month (XX.11.XXXX) in Col A, it should do the same but for cells where Col A has 11.

However, it doesn't work. Apparently, one cannot do the MID function over more than one cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`ARRAYFORMULA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en&authuser=0) for that.

This one will give a column of sums for every month there is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  SUMIF(
    MID(A:A, 4, 2),
    UNIQUE(MID(FILTER(A:A, A:A <> ""), 4, 2)),
    B:B
  )
)
```

[image]

And if you have those dates formatted as date, having the type **date**, then you can use `MONTH` instead of `MID` to get the month number:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  SUMIF(
    MONTH(F:F),
    UNIQUE(MONTH(FILTER(F:F, F:F <> ""))),
    G:G
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that was quick :) But when I execute the formula, it creates three new lines with results: https://imgur.com/a/mu6SlT7 (the marked cell is the cell containing the formula).

Comment: @JJAbrams you must have some cells with empty strings (`""`). I updated the formulas: `NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))` (which does not consider a cell with an empty string empty) is changed to `A:A <> ""`. Should be good now.

Comment: Perfect, yes @kishkin :) I had an empty line I didn't fill with a date! Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I didn't want to pollute this question, so I opened a new one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60976657/fill-missing-dates-in-google-sheets Do you know that answer as well by any chance? Thanks :)