# Output multi column instead of multi row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose

I have had the following question, that was answered here:
[Google Sheets Formula: Sum if Substring in range of cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60956211/google-sheets-formula-sum-if-substring-in-range-of-cells)

The final formula works and gives me a row for each month:

[image: 0]

The question is: Once the formula is executed, it returns multiple rows- can I get the results in multiple columns? I mean, the three return values next to each other, instead of below each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the TRANSPOSE() function. To answer the original formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(
  SUMIF(
    MID(A:A, 4, 2),
    UNIQUE(MID(FILTER(A3:A, A3:A <> ""), 4, 2)),
    B:B
  )
))
```

This will deliver the results in columns instead of rows.