# Fill missing dates in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, sumifs

I have two columns:

```
Col A                    Col B
01.02.2020               17
03.11.2020               24
03.11.2020               12
```

As I stated in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60956211/google-sheets-formula-sum-if-substring-in-range-of-cells), I tried to sum Col B, based on the month in Col A. The solution was the following formula (without the sort):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  SUMIF(
    MID(A:A, 4, 2),
    SORT(UNIQUE(MID(FILTER(A3:A, A3:A <> ""), 4, 2))),
    B:B
  )
)
```

Something I missed was the population of missing months. Therefore my question is: How can I populate the result table with the missing months and zeroes until values are entered? The desired output for the table above would be:e

```
Col A                    Col B               Col C
01.02.2020               17                  0
03.11.2020               24                  17
14.12.2020               100                 0
03.11.2020               12                  0
                                             0
                                             0
                                             0
                                             0
                                             0
                                             0
                                             36
                                             100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If just doing it for the current year, this should be enough

```
=ArrayFormula(sumif(mid(A2:A,4,2),sequence(12),B2:B))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's nice, thanks a lot! Can you explain why I can skip the whole sorting part: SORT(UNIQUE(MID(FILTER(A3:A, A3:A <> "") ?

Comment: You needed the unique and sorting before because (1) the months could appear in any order so you need to sort them and (2) they could be duplicated (which they are in your sample data) so you need unique to remove the duplicates. In my case I'm just using Sequence to generate a list of numbers from 1 to 12 and doing sumif on each of those , so those two issues don't arise (because they're already unique and in ascending order).

Comment: @TomSharpe How come this works for February? `MID` gives string `02`, `SEQUENCE` gives number `2` and they are not equal. I tried separately - not equal, but the whole formula you gave works. [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/fBPn8ol.png)

Comment: I can only give you a fairly arm-waving explanation I'm afraid - strings are converted into numbers when the context demands it e.g. if you write ="2"+"2" you get the answer 4. I guess to some extent I got lucky in assuming this would happen in sumifs.

Comment: @TomSharpe,@kishkin Thanks to both of you :)

Answer (score 1):

alternative:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(ROW(A1:A12), QUERY(A:B, 
 "select month(A),sum(B) group by month(A)"), 2, 0), 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, thanks! Is there an advantage to the other answer or is it simply an alternative?

Comment: just an alternative approach

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Player0 :)